# Parallelizing BMA in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, bayesian

I'm estimating some models using Bayesian Model Averaging. I want to paralelize the process, so I try:

```
library(BMA)
library(parallel)

no_cores <- detectCores() - 1
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)

bma_resp <- function(i) { 

  bma1 <- bicreg(
  x.quest,
  y.quest,
  wt = rep(1, length(y.quest)),
  strict = FALSE,
  OR = 20,
  maxCol = 31,
  drop.factor.levels = FALSE,
  nbest = 70
)
  return(bma1)
}
final <- mclapply(1, bma_resp)
```

Doing this I got no results at all. I'm using a 64-bit R on Ubuntu with 8 cores and 64GB of RAM.

Thanks.

Comment: do you got a sample data for us with intended output? i would like to try my solution before i post it

Answer (score 2):

I prefere the `foreach` library for tasks like this. You can do it with this one like follows. Since i don't have any data, i use the sample data from the documentation, though it always gets the same result since i can't iterate them. But you can easy check if it's working parallized.

```
library(foreach)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
library(MASS) #just used for the UScrime data from documentation of BMA

data(UScrime)
registerDoParallel(**number of cores you want to use**)

bma_dat <- foreach(i=1:60)%dopar%{
  library(BMA)
  x.quest <- UScrime[,-16]
  y.quest <- UScrime[,16]
  bma1 <- bicreg(
                 x.quest,
                 y.quest,
                 wt = rep(1, length(y.quest)),
                 strict = FALSE,
                 OR = 20,
                 maxCol = 31,
                 drop.factor.levels = FALSE,
                 nbest = 70
                 )
  return(bma1)
}
```

The output is a nested list, which you can adress seperately

For further information check the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/foreach/versions/1.4.4/topics/foreach) of foreach

Use i for the different iteration steps on your data (x.quest/y.quest) then, and change the loop-end to your amount of iterations required. You can do this easily with `length(df)` or something similar.

Comment: Don't we need to use clusterExport or equivalent to load our data to our clusters also? I did it but I am getting on error.

Comment: @boyaronur depends on your input data. If you load it before, i did not got any problems yet. But as soon as you don't want to load it from your RAM you could be correct. I don't have much experience for this one. Using foreach this way always worked for me.

Comment: I see, looks like I am doing something wrong. I just copied your code and set cluster number to 3 but I am getting Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'Uscrime' not found"
error.

Comment: @boyaronur yes there is a spelling error at `y.quest <- U"s"crime` it must be a large S. Changed that one, thanks for shouting this one out

Comment: @RicardoSilva glad i could help. If you think this is an acceptable answer to this question, you can accept it by pressing the arrow on top left of this answer. If you are still looking for alternatives or thinking this answer is not sufficient, keep it that way.